# Sum of two independent random variables (application: inter-arrival times)

Tags: distributions, convolution

In the case of specifying the requests' inter-arrival times of a web server.

Let us suppose the following case: (imagine they came from an exponential random function)

- *client1* a stream of $15$ samples of a random variable with seed $1$:

$$
c1 = \{ 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1\}
$$

- *client2* a stream of $15$ samples of a random variable with seed $2$:

$$
c2 = \{ 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2\}
$$

*client1* and *client2* are different series, however they have the same frequency:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
Value & Frequency \\ \hline
1 & 8\\
2 & 4\\
3 & 2\\
4 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

Put the values in a temporal vector, where $0$ is inative and $1$ is client doing a request:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
time &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26\\ \hline
client1&1&1&0&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1\\ \hline
client2&0&1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&1\\ \hline
server&1&2&0&0&1&1&2&2&0&2&2&0&0&2&1&1&1&1&1&2&1&1&2&1&1&2 \\ \hline
arrivals&1&1&-&-&3&1&1&1&-&2&1&-&-&3&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Then, at the instant of time $1$ the **server** received $1$ request, at $2$ two requests, and at $3$ none requests were perceived. By merging the inter-arrival times of client 1 and 2, the server's requests time line was generated. The **arrivals** row in the table corresponds to time between requests, and so we can obtain the stream perceived by the server:

$$
server = \{1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}
$$

The frequency, now, is different from client 1 and 2:

\begin{array}{c|c}
\hline
Value & Frequency \\ \hline
1 & 18\\
2 & 1\\
3 & 2\\ \hline
\end{array}

There were $9$ instants of time where there was $2$ concurrent requests at a time. I counted (is it right?) as interval of $1$. By the frequency table above, we get $18+1+2=21$ and $9+21=30$. Which is the amount of requests generated by client 1 and 2 ($15$ each).

To compute the frequency with a more expressive quantity of samples, consider the following R code:

```R
make_time_vector <- function(seed, nrequests = 1e5) {
  set.seed(seed)
  client <- as.integer(rexp(nrequests) * 10)
  # compute the instant of time where request will happen
  csc = cumsum(client)
  # set a temporal vector and mark requests as one
  req = rep(0, max(csc))
  req[csc] = 1

  req
}

# generate client 1 and 2 vector of requests
client1 <- make_time_vector(1234)
client2 <- make_time_vector(4567)

# create a zeroed vector of maximum size
maxsize = max(length(client1), length(client2))
server <- rep(0, maxsize)
# IMPORTANT:
#   here is where the things happen.
#   After these two lines, server will contain the
#   the perceived workload by it. Is this workload still an exponential?
server <- server[1:length(client1)] + client1
server <- server[1:length(client2)] + client2

# generating PDF and CDF of the server vector time.
css = which(server >= 1)
ss = diff(css)
dss = density(ss)
css = ecdf(ss)
plot(dss)
plot(css)
```

I would like to know:

- If after combine the clients (say 50 clients), will the server still receives an exponential inter-arrival time?
- How do I formalize this situation?
- Will it work for exponential with different means? Or even, will it work for different distributions?
- What is the theory I should know?

Comment: Since all quantities are integer, what you have here is a discrete-time queueing problem. A lot of work on the steady-state behaviour of such queueing systems was done by the group of Herwig Bruneel, among others (http://smacs.ugent.be/publications.php).

Comment: Your "exponential inter-arrival time" model comes from arrivals whose time of occurrence is _continuous_, and the probability of two arrivals from the two separate processes occurring _simultaneously_ is $0$. In your discrete-time model where the arrival times are integers, arrivals from the two processes _can_ occur simultaneously quite frequently, and you need to take this into account. Instead, the server seems to be discarding one of the simultaneous arrivals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a *queueing problem*.

There are two complementary measures for the same process: The interarrival times and the number of arrivals per unit time. If the interarrival times are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$ per time unit, then the number of arrivals per time unit has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

So if client 1 generates server requests at an exponential rate $\lambda_1$ and client 2 generates requests with rate $\lambda_2$, then, under some technical assumptions (to rule out simultaneous arrivals), the combined arrival rate will be exponential with rate $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.

Comment: Then, if _client1_ has the rate $\lambda_1 = 1$ and _client2_  the rate $\lambda_2 = 1$, _server_ will have $\lambda_s = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 1 + 1 = 2$. But, by the example or the simulation, I realize the rate decreases, more precisely, it tends to $1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The example is not representative, since all interarrival times are integer. I cannot speak to the simulation, since you did not present it.